# matplotlib formatting by using a list within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib

Hello I am using matplotlib, and there is this function below that I use to put data labels for 3 different graphs that have the same x values (x_indexes) but differ in y values (bar_positions, Max_profit , Max_drawdown). I need a function that will allow the data label format to be applied to all the y-values. Thanks for the help:

```
x_indexes= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
bar_positions= [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]
Max_profit= [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]
Max_drawdown= [1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
bar_char = [bar_positions, Max_profit,Max_drawdown]
    for x,y in zip(x_indexes,#insert funtion that goes through bar_char[] here#):
        label = "{:.1f}".format(y)
        plt.annotate(label, # this is the text
                 (x,y), # this is the point to label
                 textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
                 xytext=(0,20), # distance from text to points (x,y)
                 fontsize= 10,
                 rotation =90,    
                 ha='center') # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? Is the code that you posted not satisfying your requirements, and why?

Comment: @Stef I need a function to go through all the lists names within bar_char. If I put in  `for x,y in zip(x_indexes,bar_char[0])` it will only format `bar_positions` however i want it to format all 3 of the lists( `bar_positions, Max_profit , Max_drawdown`). I havent been able to do that as of yet.

Comment: You can do this purely with matplotlib and lists. But have you considered using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html) for that? pandas uses matplotlib for plotting and generally, it automatically formats the plots in a useful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current usage of `zip` has first argument `x_indexes` which has 7 elements with second argument of `[bar_positions, Max_profit,Max_drawdown]` which is list of 3 x 7 elements lists.

What you need to do is to `zip` 21 x_indexes (3 repearions of x_indexes) with 21 positions (the 3 lists concatenation)

```
bar_char = bar_positions + Max_profit + Max_drawdown  # list with 21 positions
    for x,y in zip(3 * x_indexes, bar_char ):
```